# How to access service configuration?

Tags: windows-services

I write a service using the .NET class ServiceBase. My service needs to be configured for proper operation. What is the usual way to add configuration information? I found that most services has some parameter is the registry.

e.g. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Winsock\Parameters`

Is the registry the best place to add five or six values? How do I retrieve this information? I assume that the service name might change and I want to avoid hard coded registry names in the code.

What about .exe.config files? Are these preferable for .NET based services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a normal `app.config` (`Application Configuration` item) to your project - it'll be renamed to `YourService.exe.config` in the build process, and it's the default and preferred way of configuring a .NET application (console app or Windows Service or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

> What about .exe.config files? Are these preferable for .NET based services?

Yes, they are. This way your service is self hosted - it contains everything that's necessary for its operation.

But if you wanted to manipulate the registry you could use the [Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx) class.